# Parametric representation for equation $−8x+9y−9z=13$

Tags: linear-algebra, parametric

Okay so I am stuck as to where to go from here. I know that this is a parametric solution with y and z being the parameters and x being an expression relating to y and z.(I think the solutions should be $(9/8s-9/8t-13/8, s, t)$. The empty parentheses are supposed to be 3x1 vectors with the last two being multiplied by s and t, respectively.

Solve the equation -8x+9y-9z=13

$\begin{pmatrix}x \\
y\\
z\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}  \\
 \\
\end{pmatrix}  + \begin{pmatrix}\\
\\
\end{pmatrix}*s + 
\begin{pmatrix} \\
\\
\end{pmatrix}*t$

I realize this isn't much to go by. I feel like I understand the concept of parametric solutions but have not seen it expressed like this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just $(x,y,z)=\left(-\frac{13}{8},0,0\right)+s\left(\frac{9}{8},1,0)+t(-\frac{9}{8},0,1\right)$

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer, could you mind explaining why these numbers go where? I think I know the answer but am confused by the notation.